# Plupload browse button not work inside a modal on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad, plupload

i have a plupload button inside a modal

```
<div id="container">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                    <h6 style="text-align:center;"><b>search</b></h6>

                        <a  id="pickfiles" href="javascript:;" class="custom-file-upload"  ><i class="fa fa-folder-open" ></i> browse_button</a><br><br>

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                    <h6 style="text-align:center;"><b>upload</b></h6>
                    <button type="button" id="uploadfiles" href="javascript:;" class="custom-file-upload"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" id="labelfotillo2"></i> Upload_button</button><br><br>
                </div>
            </div>
```

i add the upload refresh on modal shown

```
uploader.init();

        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            uploader.refresh();
            console.log('open');
        });
```

the console.log display the message in console but the button not work on ipad, the gallery to select images not display.

and finally i add the z-index to 99999, to the button but not work on ipad in pc works fine.

this jsfiddle works on the ipad http://jsfiddle.net/gyqk9xg3/2/, the ipad works fine and browsers updated, i delete all the code and remake it copy the jsfiddle but not working.

I do not know what to do.

any alternative solution?

Comment: The modal dialog does not open on my ipad.

Comment: is the position, width and height of a div with class "moxie-shim moxie-shim-html5", search it, and position it and resize to work on ipad, in my case was the width and height were 0.

this div is the div area to detect the touch.

Comment: when i click the launch modal, it opens mobile.twitter page in a new tab on ipad.

Comment: Does it work when you change "pickfiles" from a html a tag to something else like a html p tag?